# Set view controllers of UITabBarController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to programatically set view controllers of my custom TabBarController:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

var cameraViewController: UIViewController?
var profileViewController: UIViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self


    //self.viewControllers = [cameraViewController, profileViewController] as! [AnyObject]?
    let controllers: [UIViewController?] = [cameraViewController, profileViewController]
    self.setViewControllers(controllers as! [AnyObject], animated: true)

}
```

But with line

```
self.viewControllers = [cameraViewController, profileViewController] as! [AnyObject]?
```

I get an error that I cannot convert [UIViewController] to [AnyObject?]

and with line

```
self.setViewControllers(controllers as! [AnyObject], animated: true)
```

I get an error saying:

```
Cannot invoke 'setViewControllers' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject], animated: Bool)'
```

My problem is with AnyObject and typecasting I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the view controllers you are trying to use are declared optional:

```
var cameraViewController: UIViewController?
var profileViewController: UIViewController?
```

So you have three options:

- Don't make them optional. This requires that you initialize them with something when you initalize your `TabBarViewController`. Maybe the safest option.
- If you know that `cameraViewController` and `profileViewController` are never `nil` in `viewDidLoad`:

  ```
  self.viewControllers = [cameraViewController!, profileViewController!]
  ```
- Check if `cameraViewController` and `profileViewController` are not nil in `viewDidLoad`. This smells like bad design to me though.

  ```
  if let c = cameraViewController, let p = profileViewController {
      self.viewControllers = [c, p]
  }
  ```

So it boils down to how you initialize `cameraViewController` and `profileViewController`. Are they set before the tab bar view controllers is shown? If so, I recommend adding a custom `init` to your class.

Comment: cameraViewController and profileViewController are actually custom UIViewControllers in Storyboard. So I guess then the first option should best one?

Comment: Could you please explain why the last option is bad design?

Comment: Just my opinion: You should be sure what these variables contain in `viewDidLoad`. If they are essential to the `TabBarViewController` class they should be non-nil in there, and you should be a 100% sure about that! Now, if `TabBarViewController` is a very general class and functions with or without these two view controllers, then the story is different. But I assumed from your question that they are essential :)

Comment: How and where do you set the variables?

Comment: Both `cameraViewController` and `profileViewController` are now being set in the `required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {}` function. 

I instantiate those view controllers using `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()`

Comment: Sounds perfect! To make it explicit that you set them from within the class you can mark them `private(set)`. Just as a tip.