# Programmatically change tabBar item?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I would like to change a `TabBar Item`, when a User is logged in or not.

**For example:** i have 5 different tabBar items, all created an Storyboard.

Now i want to change the tarBar with index 2 (or tag == 2) when i user has no account. I would like to load a different rootViewController. The rootViewController is not already an item of my TabBar, i would load a totally different Controller.

What is the best way to do this? I can simple change the icon with:

```
self.tabBar.items![0].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "icon_cal_grey")
```

But how to i change the rootViewController?

Should i do it here?

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

    if item.tag == 1 {
        // ?
    }

}
```

Or should ill create a UINavigationController as RootViewController, and load here the "correct" ViewController as RootViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if user is logged in and then change view controllers of UITabBarController:

```
tabbarController.viewControllers?.replaceRange()
```

Also this may help [Set view controllers of UITabBarController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720420/set-view-controllers-of-uitabbarcontroller-in-swift)

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace second tab associated **viewcontroller** by a new viewcontroller. here is sample code, which may help you:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
UIViewController *newVC = [UIViewController new];
UINavigationController *newNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newVC];
[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:newNav];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
```

Comment: Thanks - but replaceObjectAtIndex is in Swift not available. There is only a "replaceRange" - do you know how to use it?

Comment: @derdida: I am using xcode 7.2 and i found this method ..
 let array:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
 array.replaceObjectAtIndex(1, withObject: Your_object)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
```

If you want change of viewController

Comment: No, i dont want to change only an ViewController, i want to change an RootViewController (who is not already an UITabBarItem)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for Swift

```
        let tabViewCntrls : NSMutableArray = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers)! as NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

        let vcLogin = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginScreen") as! LoginScreen

        let navRootVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vcLogin)

        navRootVC.viewControllers = [vcLogin]

        tabViewCntrls.replaceObject(at: 1, with: navRootVC)

        self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = tabViewCntrls as? [UIViewController]
```