# Hiding a tab in a tab bar in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

As the title states, how do you hide/show a tab in a tab bar where a tab bar controller is programmatically?

Or is there a better way to do this, since I want to show a certain tab containing a certain view depending on the user that logs in.

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/36306881/3918500

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850411/how-add-tabs-programmatically-in-uitabbarcontroller-with-swift check this

Comment: @James Lee Did you find the answer if so post it here.

Comment: so don't add the view controller to the tabbar controller

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have a subclass of UITabBarController:

```
final class YourSubClass: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        viewControllers?.remove(at: 0) // remove the first tab, tab index starts with 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to hide/show tab bar in ios

```
var tab = UITabBarController()
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tab.tabBar.hidden = true //set false to show
}
```

Comment: this will hide the entire tab bar . The question asked is how to hide a single tab button in tab bar.