# Swift Change ViewController of Current UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with 3 tabs that have VC1, VC2 and VC3 in each of the tabs respectively.  In VC1 I have a button that when pressed I want to REPLACE the VC1 with VC4.  How do I get the UITabBarController and update the VC array to now be VC4, VC2, VC3.  Can I do that inside of VC1 or do I need to post a notification that the appdelegate handles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set view controllers of UITabBarController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720420/set-view-controllers-of-uitabbarcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: Closely related.  
Was able to do it with: 

       if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
            let first = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatVC") as! ChatViewController
            tabBarController.viewControllers![0] = first
        }

however that changes the tab title / icon as well and not what I really wented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You can use `UITabBarController` method `setViewControllers:animated`, which accepts array of view controllers. The tabs appear in the same order as the array you pass to it (left to right). So just reorder the array and call `setViewControllers:animated` with that array. Keep in mind that the `tabBarItem`, its image and title is set per view controller. So if you reorder the view controllers your tab bar items will reorder too.

Comment: Thanks.. I did try that, and it "works", however I want to keep the tab to say HOME and when pressed returns to a VC that shows the original 6 buttons on that VC's page.  Not sure if I'm violating Apple User Design guidelines by doing this.  So show "Home VC" with 6 buttons.  Press button one.  Replace Home VC with Button1's VC.  When the Home Tab is pressed again the Home VC is displayed with the 6 buttons again.  Issue is that when Button1's VC is shown that the tab gets updated and I do not get notified when the tab is pressed again to swap back to the Home VC